# django rest api curl giving notification gateway timeout

Tags: django, rest, curl, django-rest-framework

When running the curl on rest api : 
`curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Token <token_id>" "http://localhost:4000/api/.....url"`

I am getting

*The system cannot communicate with the external server The Internet server may be busy, may be permanently down, or may be unreachable because of network problems.Please check the spelling of the Internet address entered.If it is correct, try this request later.If you have questions, please contact your organization's network administrator and provide the codes shown below.*

*Username:my username 

Source IP: my ip

URL: POST http://localhost/api/.....url

Category: 

Reason: UNKNOWN

Notification: GATEWAY_TIMEOUT*

as the response. It was working properly earlier. Can you tell me what is wrong.

I made the server run in localhost:4000 and gave it on curl but the response in giving gateway timeout.

btw im under proxy.

Comment: What does the command netstat -putan | grep 4000 returns?

Comment: It gives `tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:4000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1075/python `

Comment: Is this problem persisting or was it a temporary thing?

Comment: Its persisting. It happens all the time